# Symbolizing vector features using RGB values stored in three fields using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, rgb

I need to symbolize a vector layer in ArcMap based on RGB (or HSB - can do eiter) values found in fields in the attribute table. I'm working with up to 10 different datasets, each with over 100 features. As a result, I can't manually adjust each feature's fill attribute, nor can I use a template .lyr file and then apply its symbology.

Is there a method via Arcpy that I can use to perform this?

Looking at the documentation it appears that symbology isn't exposed to ArcPy but I'm not familiar enough to know for sure.

Otherwise, are there any third-party scripts or tools that can accomplish this?