# Using RGB values stored in field of feature class to apply colour component for ArcGIS Pro symbology?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, rgb

[Symbolizing using RGB values from Excel in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123606) and [Symbolizing vector features using RGB values stored in three fields using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37479) are questions that distil to whether it is possible to use RGB values in fields of an attribute table to apply colours direct to a feature layer in ArcMap/ArcPy.  It seems not to be possible so I advised voting for an [existing ArcGIS Idea (for ArcGIS Desktop)](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/5870).

My searches of the GUI and web for the equivalent functionality in ArcGIS Pro have also proved fruitless but I am hoping that I am wrong.

Is it possible to use RGB values stored in a field of a feature class to apply the colour component to symbols used to display them in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have submitted an ArcGIS Idea to be able to [Set ArcGIS Pro symbol
color from RGB values in attribute table](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13366-set-arcgis-pro-symbol-color-from-rgb-values-in-attribute-table):

> [Set symbol color from RGB values in attribute table](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/5870) is a popular
>   idea for ArcMap to have:
>
> > The ability to set the fill colour for a symbol from RGB values stored
> >     in the attribute table of a shapefile/feature class.
> >
> > Sometimes an attribute table contains three seperate columns - Red,
> >     Green and Blue - that define the fill color to be used to correctly
> >     symbolize a feature. Rather than manually going through each symbol it
> >     would be convenient to be able to specify the columns in Layer
> >     Properties | Symbology and the colors automatically render.
>
> This is seeking precisely the same functionality except to have it
>   available in ArcGIS Pro instead.

---

Craig Williams of Esri Redlands has since told me that this could be done using the [attribute driven symbology](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/attribute-driven-symbology.htm) that is already present in ArcGIS Pro (I'm using 1.4.1), and he is right!

To do this I added a field for hexadecimal color values, populated it using an update cursor and some code I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/214657/820534, and followed the [attribute driven symbology](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/attribute-driven-symbology.htm) help to color the polygons using the text field holding their hexadecimal colors.