# Symbology color assign based on Field value in ArcMAP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I have Parcel data for multiple small areas nearby each other.

In Each Area, there are many parcels with Landuse information with "Landuse" Field as well as each parcel is having RGB value in another field called "Parcel_RGB" with a comma delimiter respectively.

I have used "Landuse" and "Area Name" field for Symbology and the color I am applying manually.

In Each area, the land-use color will be different.

Is there any solution using Arcpy to apply color from field values.

Comment: There is no Solution.

Comment: That's because what you want to do is not possible in ArcGIS Desktop. You can do it in ArcGIS Pro: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236403/using-rgb-values-stored-in-field-of-feature-class-to-apply-colour-component-for